# In postgres how do i use the apostrophe character as a literal

Tags: sql, postgresql, literals

I am trying to convert instances of the character ’ to ', but cant work how to do it.

This just checks my syntax was okay but isn't changing the character

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$ echo "update musicbrainz.release set name = translate(name,'’','’') where name ~ '[’]+';"|psql jthinksearch
UPDATE 7284
```

If I dont escape the ' it fails:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$ echo "update musicbrainz.release set name = translate(name,'’',''') where name ~ '[’]+';"|psql jthinksearch
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...ease set name = translate(name,'’',''') where name ~ '[’]+';
```

and if do I escape it it still fails with different error

```
            ^
ubuntu@ip-172-31-39-147:~$ echo "update musicbrainz.release set name = translate(name,'’','\'') where name ~ '[’]+';"|psql jthinksearch
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...ase set name = translate(name,'’','\'') where name ~ '[’]+';
                                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `replace()`:

```
update musicbrainz.release
    set name = replace(name, '’', '''')
    where name like '%’%';
```

To escape a single quote, double it up.

Comment: Im actually translating lots of characters (I just simplified the example), but anyway thanks using two quotes worked.